# Programmatically Scrolling always not working

Tags: c#, multithreading, uwp, uwp-xaml

XAML

```
<Page
    x:Class="ScrollViewWithDifferentTypeOfContent.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:ScrollViewWithDifferentTypeOfContent"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid Height="300">
        <ScrollViewer Name="MainScrollViewer"
                      IsVerticalRailEnabled="True"
                      VerticalScrollMode="Enabled"
                    >
            <StackPanel>
                <Image Source="/Assets/icon0.png" />
                <TextBlock Name="BlockyThing">  HELLO WORLD</TextBlock>
                <ListView Name="MyListView" ItemsSource="{x:Bind obsList}" Loaded="Page_Loaded">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Item">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock  Text="{x:Bind Message}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Code in xaml.cs

```
  public static void ScrollToElement(this ScrollViewer scrollViewer, UIElement element,
        bool isVerticalScrolling = true, bool smoothScrolling = true, float? zoomFactor = null)
    {
        var transform = element.TransformToVisual((UIElement)scrollViewer.Content);
        var position = transform.TransformPoint(new Point(0, 0));

        if (isVerticalScrolling)
        {
            scrollViewer.ChangeView(null, position.Y, zoomFactor, !smoothScrolling);
        }
        else
        {
            scrollViewer.ChangeView(position.X, null, zoomFactor, !smoothScrolling);
        }
    }



namespace ScrollViewWithDifferentTypeOfContent
{
   public class Item
    {
        public string ItemName;
        public string Message;
        public static int itemNo = 0; 

        public Item()
        {
            Message = (itemNo).ToString() +  "  HELLO HELLO HELLO!!";
            ItemName = "Item" + (itemNo++);
            Debug.WriteLine(ItemName);
        }
    }

    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {

        public ObservableCollection<Item> obsList = new ObservableCollection<Item>();

        public MainPage()
        {
            for(int i=0; i<40; i++)
                obsList.Add(new Item());            
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            CoreDispatcher dispatcher = Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher;

            var ignored = dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.High, () => {
            var TEST3 = MyListView.ContainerFromIndex(4);  
            MainScrollViewer.ScrollToElement((UIElement) TEST3);
            MainScrollViewer.UpdateLayout();          
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Hi, in this code, there is an image, a text box, and a list view within a ScrollViewer, I am trying to scroll to an item within the listView (MyListView), this code works, however, sometimes it scrolls to the item specified and sometimes it does not, I understand that it probably has to do with Threading, however I want that operation to always occur after every element in the page has loaded.

Why I want this:

I need to implement navigation by scrolling the page,

Page has several elements before the listview, however I will need to scroll with respect to the listview element.

How can I ensure that the scroll always happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not recommended to have a ListView inside a ScrollViewer since this breaks the list's virtualization (all 40 items will be rendered).

You can achieve the same visual result by using the HeaderTemplate:

```
<Grid Height="300">
    <ListView Name="MyListView"
              ItemsSource="{x:Bind obsList}"
              Loaded="Page_Loaded">
        <ListView.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <Image Source="/Assets/icon0.png" />
                    <TextBlock Name="BlockyThing">  HELLO WORLD</TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.HeaderTemplate>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Item">
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock  Text="{x:Bind Message}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Then you can call the ScrollIntoView method from your code-behind, which might be more robust:

```
MyListView.ScrollIntoView(obsList[4]);
```